# Why does VS and Linux have different results for the same recursive function

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, pi

I am trying to solve for PI. To do that I built a recursive function to solve for it. Here is the code [cpp.sh/5f76s](http://cpp.sh/5f76s). On Visual Studio using the Console App project when I put in `1000` I get `3.14159265558978351`, but on `cpp.sh` and `onlinegdb` which I assume both run Linux, I get `3.22741027776071876`. Why is Linux off. What kind of work should I use next time this happens

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double Solver(int counter, int group, 
int stop, long double partialanswer)
{
round(counter);
long double Counter = counter;
if (Counter >= stop)
{
return partialanswer;
 }
//partialanswer = round(partialanswer * 
pow(2, 54)) / pow(2, 54);
 if (group % 2 != 0)
{
partialanswer = partialanswer + (4 / 
((Counter) * (Counter + 1) * (Counter + 
 2)));
 }
else
{
partialanswer = partialanswer - (4 / 
((Counter) * (Counter + 1) * (Counter + 
 2)));
 }
 group = group++;
Solver((counter + 2), group, stop, 
partialanswer);
}

int main()

{
int UserInput;
long double Answer = 0;
cin >> UserInput;
Answer = 3 + (Solver(2, 1, UserInput, 
0));
cout << "PI = " << setprecision(18) << 
Answer << endl;
}
```

Comment: Try to share the code directly inside your question

Comment: ***Do*** put the relevant code directly in the question.  That is our standard here.

Comment: @Nikaidoh Do or do not, there is no try.

Comment: You also need to share the version of the compilers you are trying and how you invoke them (what compile option are switched on).

Comment: That said, the probable reason gcc isn't experiencing a stack overflow is that it does tail call optimization (something allowed, but not required by the standard), and you are presumably running at an optimization level that supports it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a problem of the recursion.
Rather,

```cpp
 group = group++;
```

causes a problem. Just

```cpp
group++;
```

works.

Comment: And of course any sensible compiler, with warnings enabled, warns about this.

Comment: Not Visual Studio, because Microsoft